# why error message persists : setNames() doesn't work with map_dfc

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

An annoying feature when using `map_dfc` is the error message reminding you set column names like

```
New names:
* NA -> ...1
* NA -> ...2
* NA -> ...3
* NA -> ...4
* NA -> ...5
* ...
```

However, I found out even if I set column names, the error message still persists. Here is the sample codes:

```
fct <- function(x) {  return(  c(1, x, x^2) )   }

1:10 %>% map_dfc(fct) %>% setNames( str_c("C",1:10))
```

The column names have been set, but the error message still pops up.

So how can the error message be suppressed?

Comment: I found a tricky way. Just reverse the order of ```setNames``` and ```map_dfc```, it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an error, it's a message informing you that the columns have been renamed (because it's not valid for a data frame to have unnamed columns). Setting the names *after* that happens, as in your second example, doesn't have any effect.

You can avoid the message by setting the names of the input vector, which `map_dfc` will preserve for the output columns:

```r
library("purrr")

fct <- function(x) {  return(  c(1, x, x^2) )   }

1:10 %>% 
  set_names(paste0("C", 1:10)) %>% 
  map_dfc(fct)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>      C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9   C10
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
#> 3     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100
```

Alternatively, if you literally want to *suppress* it, wrap it in `suppressMessages()`, though this will also hide any other messages that `map_dfc` might generate:

```r
1:10 %>% 
  {suppressMessages(map_dfc(., fct))} %>% 
  set_names(paste0("C", 1:10))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>      C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9   C10
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
#> 3     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, it's a hint.

If you want to supress it:

```
suppressMessages(
1:10 %>% map_dfc(fct) %>% setNames( str_c("C",1:10))
)
```